# Java coding style in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

For each method, I want to add a space between the method name and the right curly bracket. For example,

```
public void setName(String name) {
}
```

I want a space between ) and {. Is it possible to automatically set this in Eclipse or somewhere? It's annoying to add this space every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default code style will add space where you want it, and it can be autoformatted on every save:

> Window->Preferences->Java->Editor->SaveActions: check "Format source
>   code"

In case you want to change some of the default styles, you can do so if you navigate to formatter and edit active profile there:

[image: Save Actions]

Answer (score 5):

in eclipse menu-->Windows-->preferences, search for the formatter, then edit then set the checkbox: insert space before opening brace

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See the eclipse manual:

http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_add_codetemp.htm

They're generally called "coding templates" for future reference in any IDE.

Answer (score 1):

There are various coding templates you can use that will change the formatting of your code to the specified specifications. But even without a custom template, the default template adds the space, you just have to auto-format your code.

**On Windows** : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

**On Mac** : <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

It will format your code and automatically add the space.

Comment: Yes. I am using the default template. The shortcut works for all, but is there a way to immediately format according to the template right after I type the code?

Comment: No there is no way of doing that. You can have it happen after save action like @Zack mentioned, but the easiest, in my opinion, is just to format the code when you are done typing.

Comment: So the best practice is to write all your code and invoke the shortcut key once every time your code is changed?

Comment: @user697911 yea, imagine if your editor was constantly changing in realtime while you are typing. That would be crazy. I just type everything I am going to write in a messy way, and periodically I just press cmd+shift+f and everything gets formatted correctly ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @EduardoDennis Visual Studio does something very similar. Every time you type ";" it fixes that line, and any time you close the "}" it fixes everything in it.